# PHP: xPath, getting all <p> tags inside a div

Tags: php, xpath

I'm attempting to access all the p tags inside a specific div. My xPath query looks like this, this should in theory return all p tags, however it only returns the first. Does anybody know how I might return all p tags?

```
//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/p
```

The structure is as follows:

```
<div id="shopMain">
 <div id="px10">
  <div id="pB30">
   <p>
    <span>Text I need</span>
   </p>
   <p>
    <span>Text I need</span>
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a regular expression

Comment: It should be achievable in the query, this would be a neater solution

Comment: You did not specify in what language you wanted. Please edit your answer

Comment: Try regex or some form of loop to return all, look at FLOWR  expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me..

```
    define('BR','<br />');
    $strhtml='<div id="shopMain">
                 <div id="px10">
                  <div id="pB30">
                   <p>
                    <span>Text I need</span>
                   </p>
                   <p>
                    <span>Text I need</span>
                   </p>
                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );

    $xpath=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col=$xpath->query('//div[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/p');
    if( $col ){
        foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->tagName.' '.$node->nodeValue.BR;
    }

    /* 
    output
    ------
    p Text I need
    p Text I need 
    */
```